# Best format to store incremental data in regularly using R

Tags: r, database

I have a database that is used to store transactional records, these records are created and another process picks them up and then removes them.  Occasionally this process breaks down and the number of records builds up.  I want to setup a (semi) automated way to monitor things, and as my tool set is limited and I have an R shaped hammer, this looks like an **R** shaped nail problem.

My plan is to write a short **R** script that will query the database via ODBC, and then write a single record with the datetime, the number of records in the query, and the datetime of the oldest record.  I'll then have a separate script that will process the data file and produce some reports.

What's the best way to create my datafile, At the moment my options are

1. Load a dataframe, add the record and then resave it
2. Append a row to a text file (i.e. a csv file)

Any alternatives, or a recommendation?

Comment: Option 1 is going to be a costly idea if you have many transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted by the second option because from a semantic point of view you don't need the old entries for writing the new ones, so there is no reason to reload all the data each time. It would be more time and resources consuming to do that.

Comment: That can also depend on the frequency of your writes, because if you must open a file for writing each second, this option will be heavier. But as you explain that you want to reload the file to add the new line before rewriting it, I made the assumptions that your writes are not this frequent.